# removing value from array not working NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a filter options, which shows checkbox. So when click on each checkbox the value should be added to array if not exists and remove the value from array if already exists and the state should be updated. I have tried using below code and it is not working.

```
const [showFilter, setFilter] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchproducts(slug, sort, pageInitial+1, showFilter));
    console.log(showFilter);
}, [showFilter]);

function filterClick (id, title) {
    const index = showFilter.indexOf(id);

    if (index > -1)
        setFilter(showFilter.splice(index, 1));
    else
        setFilter(showFilter.concat(id));
}

return (
    <ul style={{display: showMe.includes(index) ? "block" : "none"}}>
        {item.items.map((single, index1) => (
            <li key={index1}>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onClick={(e) => filterClick(e.target.value, item.title)} value={single.items_id}/> {single.items_value}</label>
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
)
```

In the above code, array insertion is working, but the splice is not working and the state is not updating.

How to alter my code to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `useEffect`. The `useEffect`'s callback will be triggered when one of dependency is changed.

[`splice` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) changes array in place (ie mutates the array). In this case your array variable (`showFilter`) is not changed, therefore `useEffect`'s callback will not be triggered.

Try using `filter` function instead:

```js
setFilter(showFilter.filter(el=> el !== id));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the original array which is not considered a good practice in React. Please use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or`[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Using slice your code would look like:

```
setFilter(showFilter.slice(index, index + 1))
```